# Reoccurring Post with GWT

Tags: java, html, gwt

```
<div class="post">
   <div class="post-user-image">
         image
   </div>

   <div class="post-content">
        <h4>
        link to user profile, firstname and last name of the post owner
        </h4>  
        <p>......messege itself......</p>
        <div class="post-footer">
            post --> date and post --> likes...
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the html code above that represents a post on a users wall, and i want this to reoccur for the number of post that user has using GWT. I don't know how to approach the problem I don't feel comfortable with the GWT integration to existing html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get familiar with GWT from the resources at the [GWT Dev guide](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide).

For your particular problem, I suggest you look at [UiBinder](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder).

You can use your HTML snip as the template for a UiBinder GWT widget. Your widget would have parameters for the image/link/content/whatever you want to display.

Let's call your widget Post. Every time you want to add a new instance to the display you might do something like this:

```
// Crete and populate our Post
Post newPost = new Post();
newPost.setUsername("XXX");
newPost.setLink("xxx");
newPost.setDate("xxx");

// Display the post.
postContainer.add(newPost);
```

Note that 'postContainer' could be anything - one of the [GWT Panels](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/layoutmanagers/gwt/), a custom container you are using to display the widgets into, etc.